# Ubuntu GUI changed after reinstalling ubuntu-session

Tags: dpkg

I have recently installed Ubuntu in my system.
I accidentally got it in command mode and used the following code to bring it back to normal mode.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session gdm3
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

but now i am getting an odd User interface  and other apps.
I am having 'xtem' and 'uxterm' instead of normal terminal.
And other few apps like entangle , mines, uxterm, vsim

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZo2J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ubuntu-desktop` is the metapackage with the standard Ubuntu desktop applications/desktop environment. It includes in it `ubuntu-session`. All the  apps you expect to see in a default Ubuntu Desktop install will be included in `ubuntu-desktop`. If you are missing some, you can install or reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`, and the applications should be back.